# Does ASP.NET MVC AntiCrsf token relies on machinekey

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

We are using the asp.net MVC out of box AntiCSRF for security. We have lots of form which uses AJAX POST with JSON.

The application will be hosted in Azure using 3 Web Servers load balanced.

Can someone please clarify below:

1. How does ASP.NET Generates the Csrf Token?
2. If it uses Machine Key, do I need to configure anything to make sure the request works on Azure non sticky load balance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the source code of the Antiforgery class I can conclude that it does use the MachineKey to derive the tokens:

[image]

Though best practices in ASP.NET farm deployment use the same machine key for other reasons as well (authentication cookies when using Forms authentication, Viewstate signing and other security related items). I'd opt to sync them across the farm regardless of the Anti forgery token. This would be yet another reason to do so :).

Answer (score -1):

It is send as a cookie and in a hidden HTML form field, both must be the same when submitted.

The idea is it that the cookie cannot be set by an outside attacker.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks

Comment: I got that. My question is how does the token gets generated i.e. using machine key. if yes does all web servers (load balanced) need to have same key

Comment: I don't think so, it's a random value